# Angular httpClient https call error

Tags: angular, ssl, https, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to call a Rest API endpoint using https. The API team has given me a Certificate folder and told me to use it to connect.

It has a a.key.pem and a a.cert.pem file. Curls requests like below are working fine-

```
curl -k -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer ZZZ" --key XX.key.pem --cert XX.pem "https://api url"
```

When my angular app does the https call its getting the below error:-
**SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efd, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd.**

I tried using **ng serve --ssl 1 --ssl-key "Certs/XX.key" --ssl-cert "Certs/XX"** but this didn't solve my problem. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The error code is a generic 'error cannot connect' message. This might indicate a CORS issue. Attempt again with CORS enabled in browser - I recommend the CORS plug-in for Google Chrome. If this is the case, add a 'control-access-allow-origin : true' header to your request.

If this is not the case, I advise posting your angularjs request code for further troubleshooting.